Zebra tc51, looking to scan qr code which will open chromium an enter the data
Using a zebra tc51, complete Newby to data wedge. I am looking to scan a qr code which will automatically open chromium and enter the scanned data.
The launcher profile will scan a code and open the dw demo then enter the data so essentially looking for the same but a different app.
Happy to pay for this.
Thanks
Tried changing the intent file but not really sure what I am doing
